# is it true that $\int_0^{\infty} \sin(f(x))dx$ bounded for all continuous $f(x)$(or at least for some of them )?

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm studying for a test and i see a lot of questions asking to decide if a given integral is bounded or not, many of this integral involve periodic functions like $\sin$ or $\cos$ and since intuitively the "negative" part of the function more or less cancels the "positive"
(this is only my intuition and not solid math by any means)

i'd like to know under what conditions $\int_0^{\infty} \sin(f(x))dx$ bounded given $f(x)$ is continuous.

is it true to say that $\int_0^{\infty} \sin(f(x))dx$ bounded for any 
continuous monotonically increasing $f(x)$? 
if yes 
what will happen if $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing or just continuous ?

Comment: $\;f(x)=-x\;$ is monotonic descreasing. Is $\;-\int_0^\infty \sin x dx\;$ bounded?

Comment: What does it even mean to say that an integral on $[0,\infty)$ is bounded? Do you mean that the function $F(t)=\int_0^t \sin(f(x))dx$ is bounded? If yes, you must say so. If no, please let us know what you do mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For an easy class of counterexamples, if $f$ obeys $f(x+1)=f(x)+2\pi$, then $\int_0^M\sin(f(x))\,dx$ is bounded if and only if $\int_0^1\sin(f(x))\,dx=0$, which is usually not the case.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

f(x)=tanh(x) is continuous monotonically increasing and the integral diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a function $f(x)$ that starts at $f(0) = 0$ and grows to $f(\infty)= \frac{\pi}{2}$.  Then

$$0 < \int_{c}^{c+1} \sin(f(x)) {\rm d}x < \int_{c+1}^{c+2} \sin(f(x)) {\rm d}x$$

So the integral is positive infinite.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the simplest counter-example is 
$f(x) = \pi / 2$ for which $\sin (f(x)) = 1$. Eventually you can note that $\int_0^\infty \sin (\pi/2)dx=\int_0^\infty dx$ is not bounded.